# Is it possible to save all rendered images (in the render buffer slots) in one operation?

Tags: rendering

I have a different render in all eight render buffer slots. In the UV/Image Editor there is an option to “Save All Images” but when I select it, nothing happens. How do I configure the save path and save all the images that are in all the slots in one operation? If "Save All Images" is not for the render buffer slots then what is it for and is it possible to do what I want to do? I am trying to discover if there is something quicker than selecting each slot and saving out the individual image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***save all images***  is for modified texture images, images that you have loaded from storage or packed in the .blend file and have been edited ,if no straight option is available  you can use a script to automate that process .
this script will save all non empty slots to the file path specified in the render tab and with the name displayed in the Image-editor and the number of the slot :  "Render_Image_slot_1.png"

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
path = scene.render.filepath
ext = scene.render.file_extension
for img in bpy.data.images :
    i = 0
    if img.type == 'RENDER_RESULT' :
        print(img.name)
        for i in range(8):
            img.render_slots.active_index = i
            try :
                img.save_render(path+img.name+"_slot_%d"%i+ext, scene)
                print("slot %d saved"%i)
            except :
                print("Slot %d is empty"%i)
```

in case you need this more then once here is the [Addon file for download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44qj7hobs1cfxm6/save%20slots.py?dl=0) install it and you'll find the entry in **UV/Image-editor**➞**Image**➞**Save_all_slots**, you can assign a shortcut for it.

[image]

to install :
[image]

Comment: The add-on for download is a blend file and not a python script? I opened the blend file but I don't see the "Save render slots" option. How do I implement the script exactly so that I can see what you show in the image?

Comment: @BrysonJack sorry my mistake I'll re-upload the file it is supposed to be a ".py" file, a minute

Comment: @BrysonJack I have updated the link , if you still have problem comment

Comment: I took the script above, made it a .py file, zipped it, installed it and confirmed it went into my add-ons directory but I still don't see the "Save render slots" menu. Weird.

Comment: @BrysonJack don't ZIP it install the directly, what version are using ( this is for 2.74 )

Comment: @BrysonJack is it working ?

Comment: @BrysonJack to install the plugin: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eP7Uj.png

Comment: Works very well, thank you. The script can not handle one of the many renders when more composite output. Now saves Besides one file from the slot. Best Regards!

Comment: don't work on 2.8 anymore, don't understand why :(

Comment: Can we get an upgrade version for 2.8x? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

2.8x

````
bl_info = {
    "name": "Render slots",
    "author": "Chebhou",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "UV/Image editor > Image >Save render slots",
    "description": "Saves all render slots",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Image"}

#upgraded to 2.80 by BD3D :)

import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator


class save_slots(Operator):
    """Save render slots"""
    bl_idname = "image.save_all_slots"
    bl_label = "save render slots"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        path = scene.render.filepath
        ext = scene.render.file_extension
        for img in bpy.data.images :
            i = 0
            if img.type == 'RENDER_RESULT' :
                print(img.name)
                for i in range(8):
                    img.render_slots.active_index = i
                    try :
                        img.save_render(path+img.name+f"_slot_{i}"+ext, scene=scene)
                        print("slot %d saved"%i)
                    except :
                        print("Slot %d is empty"%i)

        return {'FINISHED'}



def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        save_slots.bl_idname,
        text="Save render slots",
        icon='FILE_IMAGE')

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(save_slots)
    bpy.types.IMAGE_MT_image.append(add_object_button)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(save_slots)
    bpy.types.IMAGE_MT_image.remove(add_object_button)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

```
````

Answer (score 0):

Great script.

The limit was up to 8 slots.
I rewrote the script to allow for no limit.
By default, the blender is saved in the "img" folder of the destination folder.

You can also set "filepash" to any folder you like.

> for blender 2.8

```
import bpy, os

scene = bpy.context.scene
blenderpath = bpy.data.filepath
blnderfilename =  os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath))[0]
dirpath = os.path.dirname(blenderpath)

# The directory you want to build.
filepath = os.path.join(dirpath,"img")
os.makedirs(filepath, exist_ok=True)

ext = scene.render.file_extension
rendername = blnderfilename+"_"

renderimg = [i for i in bpy.data.images if i.type == "RENDER_RESULT"][0]
# set first save slot
renderimg.render_slots.active_index = 0


for renderslot in renderimg.render_slots:
    # The file path and render name (slot number) are combined here.
    path = os.path.join(filepath, rendername+renderslot.name+ext)
    try :
        renderimg.save_render(path, scene=scene)
        print("saved",renderslot.name)
    except :
        print("Slot  is empty",renderslot.name)
    # Move to next slot
    renderimg.render_slots.active_index = renderimg.render_slots.active_index+1
```

[image]

[image]

[image]